# Nested RecyclerView with two FirestoreRecyclerAdapters

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I want to have a nested `RecyclerView`, which is filled by using two `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`s, that gather two different Requests (responseOne and responseTwo) from Firestore.

In the following the scenario in short words:

1. `firstRecyclerView` --> populate with `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder>`
2. `secondRecyclerView` (nested in `firstRecyclerView`) --> populate with `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentHolder>`

Here is my code for this scenario:

```
firstRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.posts_list_recyclerview);
firstAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder>(repsonseOne) {
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Post model) {
        holder.setPostText_to_UI(model.getText());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup group, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.posts_item_cardview, group, false);


        secondRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.comments_list_recyclerview);
        secondAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentHolder>(repsonseTwo) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Comment model) {
                holder.setAuthorDisplayName_to_UI(model.getAuthorUserId());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public CommentHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup group, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posts_comments_item_cardview, group, false);
                return new CommentHolder(view);
            }
        };
        secondRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        secondRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        secondRecyclerView.setAdapter(secondAdapter);
        secondAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        return new PostHolder(view);
    }
};
firstRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
firstRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
firstRecyclerView.setAdapter(firstAdapter);
firstAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The `firstRecyclerView` works well without any problems and shows all the data.

However, the `secondRecyclerView` does not initialize, and I saw in Debug View that these two methods were not started by the code:

- `public CommentHolder onCreateViewHolder()`
- `protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Comment model)`

What can I do to get these two `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`s running?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am currently facing the same problem and there is absolutely no documentation.